# logback same timestamp for different logs

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I am using following log pattern property in log configuration of logback.

```
<property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}  %5p ${PID:- } --- [%t] : [%X{requestContext}] [%X{transactionId}] - %m%n"/>
```

Unfortunately, when I log request and response, time stamp is exactly same. However when I manually checks, response takes more than 2 seconds

```
2016-09-12 09:57:39.925  DEBUG 5955 --- [http-nio-1980-exec-1] : Request: 
2016-09-12 09:57:39.925  DEBUG 5955 --- [http-nio-1980-exec-1] : Response:
```

Since my code is not adding logging time, I believe I am missing something. What can it be?

logback is also taking up to 30 secs to log something. But i believe it is because of queue. And it has no relation with above issue.

Comment: Not a solution, but relying on `log` files for accurate time account of program execution might often be unsuccessful, specially in Server-runtimes. Even I was facing the same issue at some point of time. Why not aggregate all log-messages(with timestamp) in a `String` at the time of execution, and flush it all post successful end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find solution for that. So I used two loggers to log the request and response. Unfortunately it dint work. So, finally, I broke the logging filter in 2 separate classes. I am not sure if it is logging the correct time. But at least the time is not same now.